# Detect click on buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a header in my app. I installed the module [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/) and used their [header](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/header/). Every thing is working fine but I am not able to detect the clicks on the header. I get a syntax error when I tried to do this

```
leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#4c788', onPress={() => this.myFunction()} }}
```

or

```
leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#4c788', onPress= this.myFunction()} }}
```

or

```
leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#4c788', onPress={() => myFunction()} }}
```

or

```
leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#4c788', onPress= myFunction()} }}
```

do you have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Change `=` with `:`

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your `onPress` value using `=` instead of `:`

Try:

```
leftComponent = {
  { 
    icon: 'menu', 
    color: '#4c788', 
    onPress: () => this.myFunction()
  } 
}
```